# Specify the z-index of bubbles in AmMap?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

I have an AmMap that is very similar to [this example](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-bubbles/) ([JSFiddle Source](http://goo.gl/oEOTZB)), I just changed the data, map, title, theme, etc. The way that the bubbles are displayed are exactly the same.

My problem is that some of the bubbles are hidden under other larger bubbles. An example from the above link is China covers Mongolia, and you cannot access the Mongolia bubble without zooming in. I have tried changing the `mapData` array and having it display the smaller bubbles last and therefore on top, but it didn't help so I'm back to square one.

How can I control the z-index of the smaller bubbles?

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to set to *false* the attribute **bringForwardOnHover** on the underlying tiles.

```
{
    "groupId": "IT-62",
    "selectable": true,
    "title": "Lazio",
    "longitude": 11.8236,
    "latitude": 42.6885,
    "type": "hexagon",
    "color": "rgba(129,129,129,1)",
    "width": 14.692609617362466,
    "height": 14.692609617362466,
    "scale": 1,
    "bringForwardOnHover": false,
    "fixedSize": false
}
```